# Type of usage phrases/conjunctions

Tags: word-usage, american-english, british-english

She'd lived in Seattle her whole life, **grew up there.**

*They have got no family I know of, **no children.**

Would these types of usage be informal only and require conjunctions in formal writing.

Comment: Define "formal writing". It's unlikely to pop up in an academic paper on physics, say, but it's ubiquitous in literature.